# Convert JKS file to BKS or create BKS file

Tags: android, ssl

I want to connect server with ssl in android, I used from JKS, but I can not use JKS in android, I must change jks to bks, how can create bks file, I used from below order for conver jks to bks file : 
“keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mytruststore.jks -destkeystore mytruststore.bks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype BKS -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider”

But I could not, can I use open ssl software? How can resolve my problem? 
Best Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to create BKS format key for Android

Comment: Thank you, i downloaded this software, I opened jks file and when i wan to change key store type to bks, I get this error: "java.security.keystoreexception:java.io.ioexception: error initialising store of key store: java.security " , how can resolve my problem?

Comment: Why Do not you use crt file? you can easily create bks format from crt file without any problem

Comment: thank you for your answering, i can create file, but in android application i write this code          SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(host,port); it can not create socket, how can resolve my problem, this file is not located on server, may be it is our problem?

Comment: @user3693568 this is another question. please ask it in a separate question whit your current code and I will help if I know the answer

Answer (score 10):

The easier is using program "KeyStore Explorer" -> http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html

From Tools - Change KeyStore Type - BKS

Regards

Answer (score 6):

The correct command should looks like :

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore testkeys -srcstoretype JKS
>   -srcstorepass passphrase -destkeystore testkeys.bks -deststoretype BKS -deststorepass password -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider **-providerpath
>   C:\Personal\Work\lib\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar**

You need to supply the provider path so that it can find it when doing conversion.

Comment: I have a truststore in jks format, I am converting it into bks. But getting this: keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Comment: @Farhan Are you able to list the JKS keystore using keytool? keytool -list -keystore store_name -storepass password

Comment: yes, it was a mistake from me. I was using keytool -list -v -keystore keystore to view it. but since it was bks format thats why i was getting this error. providing the bouncycastle provider in the statment prints the keystore. Thanx for asking though

Answer (score 1):

I used that provider https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html.

While it's running it asks a password for the alias.

It works for me.

```
  keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "keystore.jks" -destkeystore "keystore.bks" -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype BKS -srcstorepass "YOUR_PASSWORD" -deststorepass "YOUR_PASSWORD" -provider "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider" -providerPath "bcprov-jdk18on-176.jar"
```